# Segmentation fault reading string with scanf() in a while loop

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
int main(){
    while(1){
            char*buffer;
            printf("inserisca una stringa \n");
            scanf("%m[^\n]", &buffer) ;
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            fflush(stdout) ;
            free(buffer) ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get a segmentation fault in this program if I put it in a `while` loop?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for the buffer.  The while loop has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the while loop.  Attempting to write to an address location without memory is undefined behavior, and would be a problem with our without the loop.

Comment: but without the while loop it works.  char *word; scanf("%ms", &word);/* input size is unknown. dynamically allocated according to the input

Comment: Is the memory for the buffer dynamically allocated from %m ?

Comment: It only appears to work.  with [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code anything can happen.  i.e. When your code attempts to write to a memory location that it does not own ( `scanf("%m[^\n]", &buffer)`  ), it might appear to work, and it might fail immediately.  You never know.  Also, the `m` conversion specifier is not C but is a GNU extension to `printf`.  It is more common, and more portable to use `"%s"` for reading a string.

Comment: @ryyker `%m` in `scanf` to allocate memory is a gcc extension. Properly used (with a space before `%` and also checking for success): `char *buffer; if(scanf(" %m[^\n]", &buffer) == 1) { ...; free(buffer); }`

Comment: @Iguananaut If OP is using gcc or clang, I think none of the duplicates addresses the real issue. In that case, the real issue is probably that OP is not checking if `scanf` succeeds and uses the pointer (and `free`ing it) even if the `scanf`/memory allocation fails.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The use of `%m` is a subtlety I missed--thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

This program will read a single line up to a new-line character. Next conversion will fail because the new-line character is still there and the format string does not accept it. If `scanf` errors out, `buffer` becomes an invalid pointer. `free`ing an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour that is likely to cause a crash.

You should always check the return value of `scanf` (and every other library function). Do not call `free(buffer)` unless the return value indicates that `scanf` has successfully read it.

Comment: I'll put the demo I wrote in the comments while the question was closed [here](https://godbolt.org/z/843ehTT5j) instead